# "failed to load module" during carthage build

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, carthage

I am trying to make a Carthage package for myself but I am running into a `error: no such module` when I actually have Carthage build the package. When I build from the workspace in Xcode everything builds fine. When I run xcodebuild from the command line, everything builds as well there too.

When I do `carthage update` however, the dependent framework builds successfully, but the Framework that uses that framework fails with the error mentioned above, `error: no such module`.

So I am left with thinking I obviously have something setup wrong in the dependent framework.

Are there any places I should be looking in the build settings of the dependent framework?

I can go to my Workspace Directory and run:

`cd directoryThatContainsWorkspace && xcodebuild -scheme TestZipArchive -configuration Release`

and it works just fine

but when I try to run the same command from the `Carthage/Checkout/TestZipArchive` I get the module not found error.

This error makes some sense to me as I probably don't have the search paths specified when I do that directly from the dir.  Again, however, `carthage update` or `carthage build` from the location of the Cartfile also fails in the same way.

The Carthage error is as follows:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/aventurella/github/testing/Carthage/Checkouts/TestZipArchive/TestZipArchive/TestZipArchive/Frontend.swift
        CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(2 failures)
/Users/aventurella/github/testing/Carthage/Checkouts/TestZipArchive/TestZipArchive/TestZipArchive/Frontend.swift:10:8: error: no such module 'ZipArchive'
A shell task failed with exit code 65:
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/aventurella/github/testing/Carthage/Checkouts/TestZipArchive/TestZipArchive/TestZipArchive/Frontend.swift
        CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(2 failures)
```

**Cartfile**

```
github "aventurella/ZipArchive" "new"

# original forked version has issues as well
# github "ZipArchive/ZipArchive" "master"
```

**Update 1**

Ok, well I addad a Mac target in addition to the iOS target, and I removed `$(inherited)` from `Framework Search Paths` in Build Settings. In fact, Framework Search Paths are completely empty for both ZipArchive and TestZipArchive.

Guess what... It builds now... So I don't know if it was the addition of the mac target or the removal of the `$(inherited)` from Framework Search Paths. Time to go back in time with git and find out.

**Update 2**

I think it was removing `$(inherited)` from `Framework Search Paths`. Just queued up my build that doesn't have the Mac target and it works again.